# How can we do automated testing and release for backend service after PR merge using Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am looking for ways to do testing for rest api’s through Jenkins pipeline after PR is merged such that it guarantees fully automated testing until release. Components are deployed on docker containers . I would like to test by connecting several other projects like upstream and downstream ? How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can define a post merge webhook. This shall trigger a jenkins pipeline which runs your test.